# Controlling Session length in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout

I set Session Timeout 10 mins using following statement.

```
Session.Timeout = 10;
```

Still my session ends abruptly within around a minute. What can be done? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default should be 20 minutes; Unless your web.config specifies 1 minute, I would check other things.  For example, are you using InProc session state and your app is restarting?

Comment: In that case, either change your situation so the app no longer restarts so often (are you deploying bins/configs often, or maybe spawning up a thread that throws an exception) or change your session state to either StateServer or SQLServer so your session doesn't get lost.

Comment: Well, for now I solved the situation by a rather crude way of setting up a 20 min cookie. Still trying to figure the problem. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this under the the `<system.web>` tag in your web.config

```
<sessionState timeout="10" />
```